# Accessing method of a Utility class in groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

Is it possible to access a method of a `utility class` from a `static method` in a service? I have a utility class that contains methods. I have tested that these methods are accessible within `Service` and `Controller`.

Now, I created a service that contains a static method. Within that method I am trying to call the method of a particular utility class, but it seemed that it doesn't work.

Is calling a method of a utility class inside a service's static method, possible?

thanks.

Comment: Can you post some sort of example of what you are trying, and the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

It´s possible to call a Static method of another class from the Service layer. Maybe you are facing some other problem that has nothing to do with the main action of calling that static method from the Utils.

You only need to import the class.

Here you havo some info about the service layer of Grails.

> http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/services.html

I would recommend you to make this checklist:

- Check if the Utils class its well constructed.
- Check if the Service layer has the import correctly writen.
- Check the way you call to this static method of the Util class.
- Check if your Service layer has this structure:

  ```
  import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
  import com.route.utils.MyUtilClass

  class BookService {

      //Example
      @Transactional(readOnly = true)
      def listBooks() {
          MyUtilClass.myStaticMethod()
          Book.list()
      }

  }
  ```

It could be helpful to have the Grails version you are working with and a code example of the service layer where you are calling to that method.